# for loop in html in c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Below is my code in HTML

```
<% for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++)
         {%>
            hello  <%  i.ToString();%>
<%   } %>
```

What i expect outupt is

hello2 hello3 hello4 hello5 hello6 hello7

But it does not append i values, it simply printing the `hello` **6** times
This is just a overview of a concept that i want to implement, i have many other alternates to do the same, but just I wanna know what i am doing wrong, because i think this can be done

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: If the answer meets your request, Its better to mark as answered.

Comment: your answer throwing compile error

Comment: @RahulSingh, your answers does not suits to my need, As i have mentioned in post, I have many alternates, and your answer is one of them,

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam You as you know 'i' got value correctly, you wanna just see that on document ?

Answer (score 2):

Small Syntax correction `<% i.ToString();%>` to `<%=  i.ToString();%>`

```
<% for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++)
{%>
    hello  <%=  i.ToString();%>
```

Comment: @kiran, u forgot the closing brace.  It should with `<%= i.ToString); } %>`

Comment: @RichardSchneider I ignored that missing,